# Angular 2 AOT error

Tags: angular, webpack

When I run AOT compilation in my application, I get this error:

```
[254]...
[255] ./client/app/main/app.module.ngfactory.ts 942 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
   [] -> factory:9ms building:292ms = 301ms
[256]...


ERROR in ./client/app/main/app.module.ngfactory.ts
Module parse failed: C:\Users\user\Documents\project\src\project\node_modules\angular2-router-loader\src\index.js!C:\Users\user\Documents\project\src\project\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\dist\entry.js!C:\Users\user\Documents\project\src\project\node_modules\angular2-template-loader\index.js!C:\Users\user\Documents\project\src\project\client\app
\main\app.module.ngfactory.ts Unexpected token (730:83)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|                     path: 'profile',
|                     component: import60.ProfileComponent,
|                     loadChildren: () => new Promise(function (resolve) {  (require as any).ensure([], function (require: any) {    resolve(require('..\\profile\\profile.module')['ProfileModule']);  });})
|                 }
|             ],
 @ ./client/app/main/main.aot.ts 6:29-62
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is causing this error? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
        declarations: [
            AppComponent
        ],
        imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            CustomerModule,
            OrgModule,
            routing,
            SharedModule.forRoot(),
            AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
                apiKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                libraries: ['places']
            })
        ],
        bootstrap: [AppComponent],
        providers: [
            {provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: AppConfig}
        ]
    })
    export class AppModule {   }
```

**EDIT 2:**

routing file that is referenced in the error.

```
const ORG_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'organisation', redirectTo: 'organisation/home', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LoggedinGuard] },
    { path: 'home', component: Org_homeComponent, canActivate: [LoggedinGuard] },
    { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent,
        loadChildren: '../profile/profile.module#ProfileModule' }
];

export const org_routing = RouterModule.forChild(ORG_ROUTES);
```

Comment: Could you provide the app.module file.?. I think it's some typo issue in that file.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: @harilalkm I added the code as an edit

Comment: Show us the place where you're defining the profile route, using loadChildren. That's what is shown in the error.

Comment: Added under Edit 2.

Comment: I don't think component and loadChildren are compatible. The ProfileComponent should be defined on the default route of the lazily-loaded profile module.

Comment: Well damn, you are correct sir. Thank you.

Comment: But wait, that is how it is done [here](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html)

Comment: No, it's not. The route with loadChildren doesn't have any component attribute.

Comment: Correct. Thanks.